# How to clear selection in ckeditor5?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm using custom toolbar for ckeditor5 and need any method to programmatically clear selection in editor area.

Is any method of clearing selection in ckeditor5 (using js code) and leave cursor position at the same place where it was?

Answer (score 0):

To clear the selection in ckeditor5,

1. You get the last position of the selected range
2. You create a range using that position
3. You set selection to the new range

```js
editor.model.change( writer => {
     //Get selected region
        let selection =editor.model.document.selection;
    //Get last position in selection
       const pos = selection.getLastPosition();
    //Create range based on last position
       const range = writer.createRange(pos);
    //Select the newly created range
                writer.setSelection( range );         
} );
```